# How to add Sphinx-generated index to the sidebar when using Read the Docs theme?

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, read-the-docs, toctree

I'd like to have a link to the automatically generated index in the sidebar when using `sphinx-rtd-theme`. I've tried adding it to the toctree:

```
.. toctree::

    first
    second
    Index <:ref:`genindex`>
```

but this resulted in

```
WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u':ref:`geinindex`'
```

from Sphinx and no other effect.

I think I could simply hardcode the index in the theme `layout.html` file, but perhaps there is some better way, not involving modifying the standard theme?

TIA for any hints!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's easy if you understand how Sphinx and Jinja work.  Unfortunately the [Sphinx docs on templating](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html) don't give you enough info if you don't.  In short, you'll have to override the template:

- Make sure you have a `_templates` folder under your sphinx docs folder.
- Make sure it is listed in your `conf.py`, e.g.  `templates_path = ['_templates']`
- Create a file inside the folder called `layout.html`.
- Put this snippet inside and save.
  The exclamation point/mark forces jinja to use the parent template.
  Don't forget it, or you'll get a recursion error.
  You only need to override the `menu` block.

  ```html
  {% extends "!layout.html" %}

    {% block menu %}
      {{ super() }}
      <a href="genindex.html">Index</a>
    {% endblock %}
  ```

Comment: This works, but this doesn't add the index link on the home page toctree, only on the sidebar toctree.

Comment: Yes, that's what the question asked for.  Combine with Steven's answer if you need it on the same page as the toctree.  Often it is there by default.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed much better than hacking the themes `layout.html` as I ended up by doing back in 2014, I've now switched to this solution (better late than never -- and the same goes for accepting this as the answer :-)

Comment: Works like charm. I did not have the layout.html file (using a ready made template) so added an empty one and then added the code given and all worked well. thanks

Comment: The above solution works only for flat html directory structures (no subdirectories). I recommend to use `<a href= "{{pathto('genindex.html', 1)}}">Index</a>` instead. Then it also works for nested directory structures

Comment: While this answer and @steve's note got me on the right page, I found that the formatting of the 'Index' entry on  my sidebar looked terrible until I surrounded it with other HTML that matched what I was seeing on the HTML generated for the sidebar for adjacent entries.  In my case, that was:

```
<p class="caption" role="heading"><span class="caption-text">Header For Index</span></p>
<ul>
<li class="toctree-11"><a class="reference internal" href="{{pathto('genindex.html', 1)}}">Index</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
.. toctree::

    first
    second

* :ref:`genindex`
```

Comment: This works but add a blank line between the toc and the index link.

Answer (score 1):

@Gringo's code got me close. Here is how to match the formatting. @brad also has this in the comments but hard to read wo line spacing. Note, read [@Gringo's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843854/2403645) on where to put this code.

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}

{% block menu %}
   {{ super() }}
   <p class="caption">
     <span class="caption-text">Indices</span>
   </p>
   <ul>
        <li class="toctree-l1"><a href= "{{pathto('genindex.html', 1)}}">Everything</a></li>
        <li class="toctree-l1"><a href= "{{pathto('py-modindex.html', 1)}}">Module Index</a></li>
   </ul>
    
{% endblock %}
```