# How can i include the `genindex` in a Sphinx TOC?

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

Sphinx generates an index named `genindex` when building a documentation and therefore [forbids to use that name for a document](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html#special-names). Now, how would I include a link to that index in a table of contents?

I've tried this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   genindex
   api


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
```

While the last line does create a link to that index in the document, the build doesn't know the reference when creating the TOC:

```
WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'genindex'
```

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/25243482/407651

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I link the generated index page in ReadTheDocs navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556423/how-can-i-link-the-generated-index-page-in-readthedocs-navigation-bar)

Comment: Can you please explain the equation: ``4 years, 2 months > 4 years, 9 months`` @Paebbles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a File `genindex.rst` with the following Content:

```
Index
=====
```

In your `index.rst` add:

```
.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   genindex
```

If you you also want to have the Link and Text "**Index**" on the Site and not only in the left Navigation then remove `:hidden:`

Comment: that's funny, the [docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html#special-names) explicitly state not to create a file with that name.

Comment: You are right. That can cause Issues. I have one Project where the PDF Creation with rst2pdf doesn't work unless I do not remove the "genindex.rst"-Hack.

Comment: that's not so funny.

Answer (score 3):

Good news, everyone! A [patch](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/10673) has been merged and was released with Sphinx 5.2.0. Now `genindex`, `modindex` and `search` can be included as TOC items without further ado.