# How can I link the generated index page in ReadTheDocs navigation bar?

Tags: indexing, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, toctree

I'm creating my documentation with Sphinx on ReadTheDocs, using their theme. The build process generates a genindex.html file, which can be referenced with:

```
Link to the :ref:`genindex` page.
```

which creates:

> Link to the [Index](http://www.dummy.com) page.

I can't add `genindex` to my toctree, for example like so:

```
.. toctree:

   foo
   bar
   genindex
```

because it's an auto generated file, which does not exist at rendertime. Moreover, Sphinx expects genindex to be a lokal file called `genindex.rst`.

How can I add it to my ToC / navigation?

Comment: Workaround: Create a `genindex.rst` file with the headline "Index" and reference it in toctree of `index.rst` (top-level). The created `genindex.html` will be replaced by the generated index, so at the end the link points to the right file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i include the \`genindex\` in a Sphinx TOC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235578/how-can-i-include-the-genindex-in-a-sphinx-toc)

Comment: @AkibAzmain please see dates of answers and you find mine existed before :)

Comment: Can you please explain the equation: ``4 years, 2 months > 4 years, 9 months`` @Paebbles?

Comment: @AkibAzmain this questions was answered 13.11.2016, the answer you linked is 18.02.2017. It's not about when a question was raised, it's about when a questions got answered. Your comment asked: `Does this answer your question?`. If you asked: Has someone asked that before, then yes, it was asked before and I didn't see that 4 years ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*As far as no one posts a better solution, I'll write down my workaround as a working solution.*

---

Sphinx creates the index as a `genindex.html` in the build root directory. It can't be referenced in a `toctree` directive, because this directive references ReST files. So how to solve it?

So let's create a `genindex.rst` file and reference it from a `toctree` directive. This also creates a `genindex.html` in the build root directory. All links are created as expected. The `genindex.html` file needs to define a headline like "Index", which is used as a link title in the navigation bar.

After writing all HTML files from ReST files, Sphinx generates its index and overwrites `genindex.html`.

**Source files:**

Source file `index.rst`:

```
.. toctree::
   :caption: Introduction

   chapter1
   chapter2

.. toctree::
   :caption: Main Documentation

   chapter3
   chapter4

.. toctree::
   :caption: Appendix

   genindex
```

Source files `genindex.rst`:

```
.. This file is a placeholder and will be replaced

Index
#####
```

**Navigation Bar Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: `Index` is correctly shown on the home page, but disappears when a chapter is open.

Comment: Oh, I was using auto-build, and the pages were not refreshed until I touched them.