# How to ensure that all Indices are corrected generated in Sphinx Documentation

Tags: python-sphinx

I am creating documentation using **Sphinx** for my Django app.

To aid / reinforce information in the documentation, I have added my own source files (`.rst`) placed both in the root folder **/docs/** and another folder **/docs/modules/** like this:

```
docs/
    abc.rst
    <folders1, 2 ...>
    modules/
        about.rst
        extra_folder/
        xyz.rst
        quest.rst
        ......
```

Now I generated the docs using `make html` at the terminal and the docs are created which I am able to view in the browser. I can see the links to my `.rst` files on the page as well as can view the contents. Using the search field I can see that the search keys are correctly searched in documents wherever they are found (including my own `.rst` files).

However, when I visit the *Index* page, I find that:

- There is no *link* to the pages created by me (e.g. **abc.rst**) i.e. my own pages are missing from the list of items displayed (if I were to click on **A**)
- Even the key alphabet is missing. A case in point is that, the alphabet **Q** is missing altogether, though I have a source file **quest.rst** in my source file and has been included in the **index.rst** (under the *toctree* directive).

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42310803/13823230) and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40579324/13823230). However I am not able to generate the missing **indices**.

**How should I approach this problem of missing Indices?**

Comment: Do you mean the file automatically generated by Sphinx with the filename of [genindex.html](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/genindex.html)? If so, these are index entries that are generated according to [Index-generating markup](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#index-generating-markup).

Comment: Please share your index.rst file contents and at least one file that is missing. What errors/warnings are reported by Sphinx?

Comment: @Paebbels - Thanks for writing. I have somehow been able to get behind the problem. Now the indices are coming correctly. The direction came from the page you had suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I link the generated index page in ReadTheDocs navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556423/how-can-i-link-the-generated-index-page-in-readthedocs-navigation-bar)